# Windows Server 2012 asking for Other User and Passcode when accessing via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

We recently noticed a change in the login process on one of our Windows 2012 Servers. When we go to login it now prompts us for "Other User"

[image: Windows Server 2012 Passcode Other User]

After which it then prompts for a User Name, Password, and Passcode

[image: Windows Server 2012 User name Password Passcode]

I have never seen the request for a Passcode when logging to a windows server before. I am able to login using my standard username and password (leaving the Passcode blank) but I am curious why it is asking for a passcode. Also it prevents my Remote Desktop Manager software from using automatic login.

Is there any way to disable the Passcode request at login? We aren't seeing this on a 2012 R2 server in the same datacenter, and nobody I have talked to knows anything about it. I don't see any recent updates that look like they could have changed the authentication process, and an online search doesn't show any results.

Comment: Neat.  Looks like two-factor auth, but I'm not sure what kind... could be an RSA token, could be an SMS code, probably could eb something else, but like you, I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer online.

Comment: Could it be a Group Policy setting was changed?

Comment: I'm thinking like @Davidw that it's either a GPO or, one of the methods that Hopeless didn't mention was a smart card reader.  We have to use those in the govt org that I work for as part of HSPD 12 (a directive straight from George Bush); not that you wouldn't know about a new directive in your company to start using smart card/smart card readers, but there is a setting in GP that allows you to turn that on/off.

Comment: Also... any new software along the lines of something like this http://www.smspasscode.com/ get installed on that server lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice of David and Brad I checked group policy using `gpresult /v` and found a policy called **Multi-Factor-Authentication-ADMINS**, which appears to be setting some registry keys in **SOFTWARE\Policies\PassGo Technologies\Defender\Defender GINA**.

It appears to be a product called [Quest Defender](http://www.quest.com/defender/) (now owned by Dell Software), and there is an entry in the Control Panel Add-Remove programs section called **[Defender Desktop Login](http://us-downloads.quest.com/Repository/support.quest.com/NC-Pass/2.0.4/Documentation/Defender%20Desktop%20Login.doc)**

So it appears we have a new two factor authentication system. I'll check with our IT department and report back if I find a way to [remove it](http://worlddownloads.quest.com.edgesuite.net/Repository/support.quest.com/Defender/5.3/Documentation/Defender_Installation_and_Administration_Guide_5.3.pdf).

Comment: Not for nothing, but why wouldn't you check with your IT department first?

Comment: @joeqwerty I already submitted a ticket... but that can sometimes take a while for them to respond. These are not production systems, so I can be a bit more aggressive about fixing things myself.